# initializing a class variable in a subclass

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I hope you guys can help me figure this out. I have this class:

```
class CsvMapping:

    __mapping = []

    @classmethod
    def initialize(cls, *args):
        if not args:
            raise AttributeError('No File/s Passed')
        
        filenames = [f for f in args]

        try:
            for file in filenames:
                with open(file, 'r') as csv_file:
                    fieldnames = csv_file.readline().split(',')
                    fieldnames = [f.strip() for f in fieldnames]

                    rows = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                    for row in rows:
                        cls.__mapping.append(row)

        except IOError as e:
            print(strerror(e.errno))
        except AttributeError:
            print('No CsvFiles passed as arguments')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    @classmethod
    def get_description_by_code(cls, code: str) -> str:
        try:
            for row in cls.__mapping:
                if row['code'] == code.upper():
                    return row['description']
        except KeyError as e:
            print('Code Not Found')
```

Now, I have this subclass in which I recreate the class variable (which, being private, is not supposed to be inherited) __mapping and override the get_description_by_code `classmethod`:

```
class CountryDb(CsvMapping):
    __mapping = []

    @classmethod
    def get_description_by_code(cls, code: str) -> str:
        try:
            for row in cls.__mapping:
                if row['code'] == code.upper():
                    return f"{row['description']} {row['province']}"
        except KeyError as e:
            print('Code Not Found')
```

what happens is I initialize the static class with something like this

```
    CountryDb.initialize(STATI)
    print(CountryDb.get_description_by_code('100000100'))
```

It does work as long as I DON'T have the method overridden. If I override the method like above, the __mapping variable of the subclass CountryDb is not used but is used to the superclass version instead.
Why's that? Thank you for your help

Comment: The name `__mapping`, used in the body of class `CountryDb`, is *entirely unrelated* to the same name used in the body of class `CsvMapping` - that's what makes such names private!  (The actual implementation is that the names get replaced with something like `__CsvMapping_mapping` and `__CountryDb_mapping`, respectively.).  If you need to refer to the name from a subclass, *don't make it private*.

Comment: i know that, i made private because of this, i don't want to process the superclass variable, i want to use the subclass one and it works like a charme, the variable _CountryDb__mapping gets filled up with the values i want. The problem is when I override the get_description_by_code method in the subclass, this method uses the _CsvMapping__mapping variable instead of _CountryDb__mapping.

Comment: If you really want that, then you'd need to duplicate the `initialize()` method into the subclass as well, so it's setting the same private variable that `get_description_by_code()` is reading.  But in that case, it's unclear what advantage you'd get from subclassing `CsvMapping` at all.

Comment: but it works, without the method override it works, the mro is respected and it does work, the right variable gets used, it stops doing it right when i add method! if the subclass was like: ```class CountryDb(CsvMapping): __mapping``` everything is fine, when i override the method it blows.

Comment: If you don't override either method, then they're both using the base class version of the private variable, and it's exactly the same as if you'd instantiated the base class directly.  The MRO has absolutely nothing to do with any of this; the sole factor determining which class's version of a private name is applicable is the class definition that physically contains the method definition.

Comment: I'll play it out and see what i'm missing here. I'm new in stackoverflow but i'll figure out how to give a positive acknowledge Jason. Just give me 2 or 3 days, i drank a fair amount of gin and i'm not able to think

Comment: Basically the "private" modifier works the same(C++,Java) way wherever you use a regular class with istance method and attributes or class with Class method and attributes? This Class method has been confusing me bit, given that "static" also exists but just defines a "helper" related someone to the class. The oop implementation I'm used to is deceiving. Why should i use class object instead of static objects?